# How to listen to button interactions from other bots I invited to my server, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I can listen to button interactions from my own bot that I made for my discord server just fine. There are data on the console.

Here's the code

```
client.on("interactionCreate", i => {
if (i.isButton()) {
console.log(i);
}
})
```

My question is how to listen to other bots like Mee6? Using the same code and then interacting with MEE6 like pressing buttons on the giveaway embed does not generate any data on the console. Is it possible to listen to interactions from other bots that I did not create? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the interactionCreate event only works for slash commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway event `INTERACTION_CREATE` is only for your application. You cannot receive other applications' interactions.